# ANTLR cannot generate java code as of version 4.7.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, antlr, antlr4

I have installed the ANTLR IntelijIdea plugin latest version 4.7.2 and tried to generate the **java** code for the grammar. (Right-click on the Grammer file and execute "Generate ANTRL Recognizer)

However, I get below error.

```
2019-05-13 10:51:08: antlr4 -o E:\Work\FE\CGUI\mitscript4j\src\main\java\gen.antlr -Dlanguage=java -listener -visitor -lib E:/Work/FE/CGUI/mitscript4j/src/main/antlr4 E:/Work/FE/CGUI/mitscript4j/src/main/antlr4\MITS.g4
error(31):  ANTLR cannot generate java code as of version 4.7.2
```

Below is my grammar

```
grammar MITS;
main: 'Hello ' name '!';
name: ANY+;
ANY: .;
```

Can anyone tell where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer

In the "Configure ANTLR" window I have mistakenly specified the language as "java".
The problem resolved after renaming to "Java"

Comment: You can mark your own answer as *the* answer. If you don't do that this question will stay open forever and may unnecessarily attrack people to answer it.

Comment: @Mike Lischke will do it within another two days. Can't accept it as the answer on the same day the question is posted.